# WCF : Keep inner exceptions across nested service calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a solution that runs WCF calls this way :

Web API -- (WCF) -> Main service -- (WCF) -> Sub service.

Let's say Sub service throws an exception I want the main project to throw an exception as well. In the end, I want to report the full stacktrace to the main project.

Problem is that I did not manage to keep the called sub service stack trace beyond 1 WCF call.

If possible I would like to have something like this when an exception is thrown:

```
SubService.ThrowException()
SubService.ProcessRequest()
==== End of inner exception ====
MainService.CallSubService()
...
MainService.ProcessRequest()
==== End of inner exception ====
MainProject.CallMainService()
...
```

.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMainService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(System.Exception))]
    JobInformation ProcessJob(JobInformation info);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISubService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(System.Exception))]
    JobInformation ProcessJob(JobInformation info);
}


public class SubServiceClient
{    
    public JobInformation ProcessJob(JobInformation info)
    {
        return (Service.ProcessJob(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid using a workaround by returning exception and manually throwing them in the callee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way : I will use a workaround.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProcessingService
{
    [OperationContract]
        JobInformation ProcessJob(JobInformation info, out Exception exception);
}
```

But watch out for the size of the serialized exception. You will likely have to configure WCF to accept larger data.